# Create an array of objects from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object as follows:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "dataLockVersion": 0,
    "auditData": {
      "createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362",
      "createUser": "XXX",
      "updateDate": null,
      "updateUser": null
    },
    "property1": 14021,
    "property2": {...},
    "property3": "Obj"
  }
```

And I have an array that contains multiple objects in that format.

I want to create a new array of objects from this array, which will contain objects in this format :

```
{
    "property1": 14021,
    "property2": {...},
    "property3": "Obj"
  }
```

This is what I tried :

var result = [];

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    delete arr[i].auditData;
    delete arr[i].dataLockVersion;
    delete arr[i].domainObjectDescription;
    delete arr[i].id;
    result.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: I have updated my answer by adding a new method with a `Innovative` way! you can check it too.

Comment: You can use restructuring assignment , check my answer

Answer (score 3):

use map and object destructure

```
const result = array
                   .map(
                       ({ property1, property2, property3 })
                       => ({ property1, property2, property3 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for this:

```js
let arr =[{ "id": 1, "dataLockVersion": 0, "auditData": { "createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362", "createUser": "XXX", "updateDate": null, "updateUser": null }, "property1": 14021, "property2": {"x" :1}, "property3": "Obj" }, { "id": 1, "dataLockVersion": 0, "auditData": { "createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362", "createUser": "XXX", "updateDate": null, "updateUser": null }, "property1": 14021, "property2": {"x" :12}, "property3": "Obj" }];
  
let result = arr.map(({property1,property2,property3})=>Object.assign({},{property1,property2,property3}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```js
 var data = [
    {"id": 1,"dataLockVersion": 0,"auditData": {"createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362","createUser": "XXX","updateDate": null,"updateUser": null},"property1": 14021,"property2": {},"property3": "Obj"},
    {"id": 2,"dataLockVersion": 1,"auditData": {"createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362","createUser": "YYY","updateDate": null,"updateUser": null},"property1": 140221,"property2": {},"property3": "Obj3"}
];

var res = data.map(function(m){return {property1: m.property1, property2: m.property2, property3: m.property3};})

console.log(res);
```

---

Or if you like tricks **and** all values are `string` or `number` or object that contains them, you can use this (in very heavy objects is not recommended):

```js
let data = [
        {"id": 1,"dataLockVersion": 0,"auditData": {"createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362","createUser": "XXX","updateDate": null,"updateUser": null},"property1": 14021,"property2": {},"property3": "Obj"},
        {"id": 2,"dataLockVersion": 1,"auditData": {"createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362","createUser": "YYY","updateDate": null,"updateUser": null},"property1": 140221,"property2": {},"property3": "Obj3"}
    ];
var res=[];
JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"(property1)"\:(.+?),.+?"(property\d+)"\:(.+?)(?=})/gi, function(a){res.push(JSON.parse("{"+a+"}"));});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I had a similar problem I was trying to solve for like 6 hours, that property assignment with map and function saved my sanity

Comment: I am glad it was useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [lodash.pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick) as a oneliner clean and efficient solution.

Pretty often it turns out that this kind of logic will be needed in other parts of the app.

In your case it would be:

```
var newArrayWithPickedProperties = array.map(item => {
  return _.pick(item, ['property1', 'property2', 'property3']);    
})
```

If you go this way ensure you [import only lodash.pick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick) not entire lodash library.

Answer (score 0):

If data is from a JSON string, the [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples) can be used to exclude properties :

```js
var json = '{"id":1,"dataLockVersion":0,"auditData":{"createDate":"2018-09-18T11:41:28.362","createUser":"XXX","updateDate":null,"updateUser":null},"property1":14021,"property2":"{...}","property3":"Obj"}'

var obj = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => /id|data/i.test(key) ? void 0 : value)

console.log( obj )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have n number of property with fixed 1st 3 keys, you can do destructuring assignment.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
let data = [
    {"id": 1,"dataLockVersion": 0,"auditData": {"createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362","createUser": "XXX","updateDate": null,"updateUser": null},"property1": 14021,"property2": {},"property3": "Obj","property4":"yo","property5":"hey"},
    {"id": 2,"dataLockVersion": 1,"auditData": {"createDate": "2018-09-18T11:41:28.362","createUser": "YYY","updateDate": null,"updateUser": null},"property1": 140221,"property2": {},"property3": "Obj3"}
];
const arr=data.map(a=>{
           let {id,dataLockVersion,auditData,...props}=a
           return props;
          }
       )
console.log(arr);
```